# How to place POST TITLE any location inside the posts page

Tags: theme-development, wp-title, get-the-title

I am editing the single.php file, and I want post title to appear inside a particular div. Since my theme doesnt show the post title, I want to retrieve the post title on posted article page.

" >

```
<div class="entry-content">
```

POST TITLE HERE PLEASE, HOW TO GET THE POST TITLE

```
        <?php total_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <!-- edit -->

    <!-- edit -->
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'total' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you place it within "The Loop", you can use `the_title()` function, which will display the title. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title . The function will not return anything outside of "The Loop".

Note that `get_the_title()` is similar, but does not display the title. If you used that function, you would `echo get_the_title()` .

Note also that Child Themes are recommended, since you don't want any theme updates to overwrite your changes.

Comment: Thank you Sir, for your reply,
I didnt think of this simple thing LOL
echo get_the_title()

Comment: No problem. Some of the functions in The Loop return a value, and others echo/print the value. Usually, the get_something() returns a value, but the something() echo/prints the value. (A checkmark on my answer is appreciated if it was a good answer for you.) Thanks.